# Size of Needle in strstr function

Tags: c, strstr, string.h

This is a simple question, but, when I am using the strstr function, why does the size of the needle have to be at least one character bigger than the actual text in the needle? Is this because of the null character?

When I put the needle as needle[1], it does not work. Why is it fine to put the exact number of characters for the haystack?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
{
   const char haystack[21] = "IDontUnderstand?Help!";
   const char needle[2] = "?";
   char *buffer;

   buffer = strstr(haystack, needle);

   printf("The substring is: %s\n", buffer);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: C-style strings need to be terminated by `'\0'`, otherwise nothing identifies the end.

Comment: As long as you don't modify the content, use `const char* needle = "?";`. Problem solved.

Comment: Instead of `const char haystack[21] = "IDontUnderstand?Help!";` you can write `const char haystack[] = "IDontUnderstand?Help!";`. In the latter case the size that is needed for the array is calculated by the compiler.

Comment: Side note: If your needle is a single character you can use `strchr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, both strings should have the null terminating character at the end (`'\0`) because the function otherwise does not know when to stop reading the string:

Take the `strlen` function. It reads the length of the string up to the null character and can be implemented like so:

```
size_t strlen(const char* str)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    for(; *str; ++str, ++len);
    return (len);
}
```

Note the condition is `*str`, which also can mean `*str != 0`, which shows that the for loop increments the string and length until a null character is found.

However, if a null terminator is not given (e.g. you allocated `char[5]` for `"Hello"`, when it should actually be `char[6]` - `"Hello\0"`), it is pure luck if the function you use stops at the end of "hello".

To make it easier, if you are writing a character array, you could instead not include the number in the braces and allow the compiler to deduce it for you to ensure that there is a null terminating character:

```
const char haystack[] = "IDontUnderstand?Help!";
const char needle[] = "?";
```

Note that you cannot put `const char haystack[strlen("IDontUnderstand?Help!") + 1] = "IDontUnderstand?Help!";` as `strlen("IDontUnderstand?Help!") + 1` is not a constant value.

However, if you want to dynamically allocate the memory, you can use the `strlen` to help:

```
char* get_str_buffer(const char* value)
{
    char* buf = malloc(strlen(value) + 1);
    strcpy(buf, value);
    return (buf);
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *haystack = get_str_buffer("IDontUnderstand?Help!");
    const char *needle = get_str_buffer("?");
    char *buffer;

    buffer = strstr(haystack, needle);
    printf("The substring is: %s\n", buffer);


    free(haystack);
    free(needle);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> why does the size of the needle have to be at least one character bigger than the actual text in the needle? Is this because of the null character?

Yes ,exactly it is because of the `null character`. If you see the format of [`strstr()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) it is this -

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
```

And arguments needed are -

`haystack -This is the main C string to be scanned.`

`needle -This is the small string to be searched with-in haystack string.`

As `needle` is small string , thus `'\0'` is required to terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't fine for the haystack either. You indeed need room for the trailing NULL byte, so that functions know where the string ends. Otherwise they will keep on reading memory until they encounter a NUL that happens to be there.

If you leave off the extra char from haystack, looking for the needle `"f"` may actually return a result, all depending on what the memory happens to contain.

This is part of why it's better style to use `const char*` to hold string literals. Use arrays only when constructing values in code.

Comment: Reading past the end of the array is undefined behaviour. It *might* manifest itself as you described, but saying that that *will* happen is wrong.

Comment: True. Depending on memory protection in place it could also segfault immediately. Or it could malfunction in a number of creative ways.